# ajax like/unlike button not switching back

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to make a like button on a page and cant seem to get it to work right. Basically there are three function that use ajax to send the data to a php page that updates the database. Ive checked the db and all three update correctly. If the user doesnt originally like and clicks, it correctly shows the unlike button but then, if you click unlike it doesnt switch back (although it does update the database).

Is this the correct way to set this up? Im pretty new to ajax and am not sure if this is the right approach. THanks in advance
Steve

```
public function likesScript($p){?>
    <script>

//display list of people who like this
    function getLikes(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "likelist.php",
        data: { p: "<?php echo $_GET['p']?>"}
    }).success(function(res) {


         //check to see if current user likes this   
        if($('li#<?PHP echo $_SESSION['userId']; ?>').length){
            $(".Like").addClass('hidden');

            $(".UnLike").removeClass('hidden');
        }
        else{  
            $(".UnLike").addClass('hidden');
            $(".Like").removeClass('hidden');

        }

        $("#likedBy").append(res); 
        console.log(res);

    });
}


function removeLike() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "likedata.php",
        data: { arg1: "<?php echo $_SESSION['userId']?>", arg2: "<?php echo $p;?>", arg3: "0" }
    })

    getLikes();


    return false; 
}


function addLike() {


    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "likedata.php",
        data: { arg1: "<?php echo $_SESSION['userId']?>", arg2: "<?php echo $p;?>", arg3: "1" }
    })


    getLikes();


    return false; 
}



$(document).ready(function() {   getLikes();
 $(".UnLike").live('click',removeLike);
 $(".Like").live('click',addLike);


});



    </script>
```

likelist.php:

```
<?php
require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/view.class.php';

$view = new view();
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/profile.class.php';
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/init.php';  

$profile = new profile($dbh);

if(isset($_POST)){
$p = $_POST['p'];


$view->printLikes($profile->getLikes($p));


}
```

likedata.php:

```
<?php
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/profile.class.php';
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/init.php';  

$profile = new profile($dbh);

if(isset($_POST)){
$liker = $_POST['arg1'];
$likee = $_POST['arg2'];
$likeYesNo = $_POST['arg3'];

$profile->insertLikes($liker, $likee, $likeYesNo);


}
?>
```

Comment: Does it switch back if you refresh the page?

Comment: Did charlietfl's answer solve it?

Comment: I added it. The first one just displays the list of users in li tags the second just updates the database if addLike or removeLike is called

Answer (score 2):

AJAX is ayshcronous so the `getLikes` functions will fire before the AJAX is completed in both `addLike` and `removeLike`. You definitely need to put `getLikes` into the success callback of `$.ajax` so it doesn't retrieve data that may not have been updated

```
function addLike() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "likedata.php",
        data: { arg1: "<?php echo $_SESSION['userId']?>", arg2: "<?php echo $p;?>", arg3: "1" },
        success: getLikes
    })

}
```

Comment: I still can't get it to work..unless I refresh the page...if you see click like it changes to unlike but then if you click unlike it doesnt switch back....what about the bottom part of the script. should they be inside the document.ready() part?

Answer (score 1):

Ok... this is what I have learned from using ajax repeat calls...

IE hates them and sometimes they just don't work the way they should.

Try this

```
function addLike() {

    var randnum = Math.floor(Math.random()*1001); //Add This Here on all Ajax Calls

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "likedata.php",
        cache: false, //Add This Here - Assists in helping Browsers not to cache the Ajax call
        data: yourdata + '&random=' + randnum, // Add this to the end of your data you are passing along *'&random=' + randnum,*
        success: function() {
              getLikes();
        }
    })

}
```

Adding a random piece of data causes the browsers to think its a new call.

---

Also, the **random=randnum** wont effect anything on the php side.

Comment: I do this for ajax signin pages when I need to test signin information, set cookies via php, and show the user signin success without a page refresh...works great.

Comment: cool. I actually switched the .append in getLikes to .html and it works now in chrome. I'll test it in ie..

Comment: Awesome! Did you add the "random" variable too?